# How to read JavaScript object with XPath/HTMLAgilityPack

Tags: c#, javascript, xpath, html-agility-pack

For my crawler project, I need to get product details from JavaScript object.

How can I effectively get object details from the following JavaScript? I Use XPath and HTMLAgilityPack.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var product = {
        identifier: '2051189775',     //PRODUCT ID
        fn: 'Fit- Whiskered Dark Wash Skirt',
        category: ['sale'],
        brand: 'Brand Name',
        price: '22.90',  // this would be the discount price
        amount: '31.80',  // this would be the original price
        currency: 'USD',
        //List can me even more.
    };
</script>
```

I've not tried getting details from JavaScript objects before. I was getting details directly from HTML for other crawlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the HTML Agility Pack doesn't evaluate any of the contents of the HTML, the javascript code should just be considered plain text. Use the `SelectSingleNode` method to find the piece of Javascript, then just grab the InnerHtml to get to the contents.

Either find a C# javascript parser ([Iron JS](https://github.com/fholm/IronJS) for example) or write a parser using standard text manipulation techniques (`String.*` or `Regex` to extract the bits you're after.

Once you have the bits between the curly brackets you could parse them using a before mentioned parser or a library like [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx), since the pieces between the curly brackets seems to be valid json.