# How to extract HTML source code using HTML Agility Pack in WinForms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, html-agility-pack

How can you extract certain parts of a HTML website (e.g. the code of [this link](http://currency-api.appspot.com/api/GBP/USD.json?key=efaeba3ccb2653bb0d8bf9c77fd8ac6c17f0d0c1)) using HTML Agility Pack?

This is what the link looks like - source code and when viewed:

```
{"target": "USD", "success": true, "rate": 1.682, "source": "GBP", "amount": 1.68, "message": ""}
```

I'd like to have the part where it says

> 1.682

My use is for VB.NET WinForms (Visual Basic 2010).

I'm aware that it can be handled using JSON because that's how it's formatted, but I'd prefer (if possible) to keep using VB.NET and simply download the source code (which is exactly the same as the viewable code) and then extract the useful information, unless there is a better/easier API.

Also, how can you remove parts of a string once you have downloaded the website source code, e.g. remove the first ***x*** number of characters and then the last ***y*** number of characters? If this is difficult or not possible, then is there a way of removing all text until a certain word, and all after a certain word?

Comment: I think you are confusing JSON and AJAX.  JSON is a data format.  AJAX is a (typically) web-client technology.  I would suggest using Newtonsoft JSON parser.

Comment: That's not html, It is JSON.

Comment: @Sriram If you look up the main website they say it is in JSON. To me it doesn't matter anyway...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't parse JSON with HTMLAgiligyPack (explained in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17740821/how-to-read-javascript-object-with-xpath-htmlagilitypack)).

There are many possibilities to do this. The best and the secure one would be to use the [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) library (as already suggested by @Dan-o) in order to parse the JSON response:

```
dim response = "{""target"": ""USD"", ""success"": true, ""rate"": 1.682, ""source"": ""GBP"", ""amount"": 1.68, ""message"": """"}"
dim responseObject = CType(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response), JObject)
Console.WriteLine(responseObject.Property("rate").Value)
```

If you are sure, that the response returns always the same fields in the same order, another trivial (and naive) solution would be to use [String.Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
dim response = "{""target"": ""USD"", ""success"": true, ""rate"": 1.682, ""source"": ""GBP"", ""amount"": 1.68, ""message"": """"}"
' remove the leading curly brace {
response = response.Substring(1)
' remove the last curly brace }
response = response.Substring(0, response.Length - 1)
' split on , - result is blocks "key:value"
dim tokens = response.Split(",")
' take the 3th one "rate:nn.nnn", split on :
dim rate = tokens(2).Split(":")
' take the second value from the array at index 1
Console.WriteLine(rate(1))
```

Response is:

```
1.682
```